# Haskell Immutable data structure - the Map data type

Tags: haskell, data-structures, immutability, key-value

I am confused about the this data type in Haskell - Map.  In particular, there is a function call insert (from the Data.Map module) which allows you to append new values to the Map data structure.  So, here is my confusion.  If haskell data structure is **immutable**, how can you insert new data into an existing Map data structure?

Comment: You can't, you construct a new map that contains the new key.

Answer (score 6):

`insert` doesn't actually modify the input `Map`. It returns a *new* `Map` that contains the same entries as the original `Map`, plus the one you are inserting.

Underneath the hood, the compiler may not actually have to copy all the old entries to a new `Map`, though; it can reuse the original if it determines that nothing else is using the input `Map`. Immutability is a property of the *language*, not necessarily the *implementation* of the language.

Comment: Indeed, in a balanced BST-based implementation, `insert` only needs to copy O(log N) nodes of the tree, and reuse much of the old (immutable) tree.

Comment: Compilers are *allowed* to modify a value in-place if it can determine that no references are held to the old value, but as far as I know none of them *does*. But not all is lost: `Map` is implemented as a tree, and unchanged subtrees can be (and are) shared between the old `Map` and the new one. This is permissible whether something else is using the input `Map` or not (because immutability guarantees that the sharing won't cause aliasing problems).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an example will make this clearer.

```
Prelude> let map1 = empty
Prelude> map1
fromList []

Prelude> let map2 = insert "Lemon" 6 map1
Prelude> map2
fromList [("Lemon", 6)]

Prelude> map1
fromList []

Prelude> let map3 = insert "Lime" 7 map2
Prelude> map3
fromList [("Lime", 7), ("Lemon", 6)]

Prelude> map2
fromList [("Lemon", 6)]

Prelude> map1
fromList []
```

Each time we define a new variable (`map1`, `map2`, `map3`), the previous version of the `Map` remains completely unchanged. Once we have defined that (for example) `map1` contains the key `"Lemon"`, nothing can ever change that definition. We can create a new map that contains additional keys (or fewer keys, indeed), but we cannot change `map1` itself.